# How to specify "strict" priors for fixed coefficients in rstanarm?

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, rstanarm

How do I provide a prior distribution for a coefficient with mean in the range 1e-05 and standard deviation (sd) in the range 1e-06?

What are the distributions to choose for such high precision (sd <= 1e-06) parameters in rstanarm?

1) Student t family

2) Hierarchical shrinkage family

3) Laplace family

4) Dirichlet family

5) others

I have tried using `prior = normal(location = 1e-05, scale = 1e-06, autoscale = FALSE)`, but it takes a lot of time for sampling.

Answer (score 0):

I think `prior = normal(location = 1e-05, scale = 1e-06, autoscale = FALSE)` is your best bet. The fact that it takes a lot of time for sampling is not an indication that anything is wrong with the draws it produces. But I would multiply the outcome by 1 million or divide the predictor by 1 million so that `prior = normal(location = .1, scale = 1, autoscale = FALSE)` is sensible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, re-scaling has significantly improved sampling time. 

Also, what does prior_PD = TRUE and QR = TRUE mean inside stan_lmer(...) call? How does it effect the computation?

Comment: Both (actual all) of those arguments to `stan_lmer` are [documented](http://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/stan_glmer.html).